# Quadratic Equation problem using pointers

Tags: c++

I successfully made a program to find a solution of the standard form quadratic equation given the three coefficients. I am now trying to simplify the result, as to get rid of the "/2a" on the bottom. Hence the simplify() function.

I have started to create the simplification function, and am attempting to divide the imaginary part of the solution as well as the real part of the solution by 2a. Somehow, it gives the error:

```
"error:invalid operands of types 'int' and 'double *' to binary 'operator*'" on lines 105 and 106.
```

I suspect it has to do with the pointers and references that I am passing as parameters. I am new to that idea.

Also, just an aside, I have never actually seen "/=" be used. Is the permissible? I know "+=" can be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib> //simplify the answer
using namespace std;

int count = 0;
//prototyping
double ans_1(double, double, double);
double ans_2(double, double, double);
double nanhe(double, double, double);
void simplify(double*, double*, double*);

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    cout << "Quadratic Equation Solver \n";
    cout << "Enter a value for a: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter a value for b: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter a value for c: ";
    cin >> c;
    cout << endl;

    if (isnan(sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c)))) {
        count++;
    }
    if (!count) {
        double answer01 = ans_1(a, b, c);
        double answer02 = ans_2(a, b, c);
        cout << "X=" << answer01 << endl;
        cout << "X=" << answer02 << endl;
    }
    else if (count) //could route these imag ones to separate funcitons instead of count++
    {
        double answer01 = ans_1(a, b, c);
        double answer02 = ans_1(a, b, c);
        cout << "X=(" << -b << "+" << answer01 << "i)/" << 2 * a << endl;
        cout << "X=(" << -b << '-' << answer02 << "i)/" << 2 * a << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}

double ans_1(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double ans1;
    double temp_c = sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c));
    if (isnan(temp_c)) {
        temp_c = nanhe(a, b, c);
    }
    if (!count) {
        ans1 = ((-b + temp_c) / (2 * a));
    }
    else if (count) {
        ans1 = ((temp_c));
    }
    simplify(&a, &b, &ans1);
    return ans1;
}

double ans_2(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double ans2;
    double temp_d = sqrt((b * b) - (4 * a * c));
    if (isnan(temp_d)) {
        temp_d = nanhe(a, b, c);
    }
    if (!count) {
        ans2 = ((-b - temp_d) / (2 * a));
    }
    else if (count) {
        ans2 = (temp_d);
    }
    simplify(&a, &b, &ans2); //line under this should alter ans2 so its returning the simplified version instead, or just make a new variable instead of ans2
    return ans2;
}

double nanhe(double a, double b, double c) //still need to apply simplify() to nanhe
{
    double temp_help;
    temp_help = sqrt(-1 * ((b * b) - (4 * a * c)));
    count++;
    return temp_help;
}

void simplify(double* a, double* b, double* ans) //only run if complex
{
    ans /= (2 * a);
    b /= (2 * a);
}
```

Comment: Use `*` in the simplify() function.  And consider that C++ allows you to declare its parameters as double& instead of double*.  And go shopping for a decent IDE so you don't have to guess where the syntax error is located.

Comment: void simplify(double* a, double* b, double* ans)

Comment: still not working...

Comment: Concerning your `+=` and `/=` question:
`x #= y` is shorthand for `x = x # y` where # is any valid operator. The most common used are: `+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `|=` `&=` `^=`

Comment: Got it but, i tried to change some line and I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access or alter the value pointed by the pointer, not the pointer itself:

```
void simplify(double* a, double* b, double* ans) //only run if complex
{
    *ans /= (2 * *a);
    *b /= (2 * *a);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Or, as said by @Hans Passant:

> And consider that C++ allows you to declare its parameters as double&
>   instead of double*. And go shopping for a decent IDE so you don't have
>   to guess where the syntax error is located.